# Drilled hole through wall stud

Tags: drywall-anchor

First post here... I made a mistake and would like some suggestion on how to properly fix it.

I wanted to mount window curtain rods with toggle anchors. I drilled 3/8th inch hole through drywall, wall stud and hit concrete. To make it worse, it’s two holes on either side.

How can fix these holes in wall stud? I am worried it will affect something structurally.

Answer (score 5):

With no more specifics than that I would say you should have no concern that one 3/8 inch hole drilled through one stud could present any structural problem. There is so much redundancy in standard stud construction that there is a vanishingly small probability this could have any practical consequence.

If the hole is where you want it and it is not on the edge of the stud, then use the right size of plastic sleeve anchor and screw in this hole to hold the curtain rod. That would be stronger than a toggle bolt into drywall.

Comment: Sorry if info wasn’t enough. It’s two 3/8 holes on each wall stud either side. So four holes in total. I already drilled smaller hole with wood screw 1” away from these holes. Just wanted to fill them and close the hole. Can I use wood filler for wall stud and compound for drywall?

Comment: Just spackle/ joint compound the drywall and don’t worry about the stud.

Comment: The holes are perfectly usable for curtain rods and drilling a second hole really wasn't necessary. If your curtains can bring down a stud, there is something seriously wrong with that stud...

Answer (score 0):

Your first answer is correct. A couple of holes that size shouldn't matter to the wall strength. It's done all of the time to run wire and piping through those studs.
And the holes would hold an anchor as noted above.
It's not clear if the studs are on edge or flat or what the concrete is behind them.
If it really concerns you, and you need to put the holes somewhere else, or you can't get an anchor in there, the way to fill those holes is to put 3/8" wood dowels with some wood glue in there, about 1/4" short of the wall surface. Put some Fix-All in the remaining surface cavity, leaving room for some spackle or painter's caulk to hide the hole. Or you could put a screw into the stud or dowel.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It’s drywall, wall stud and concrete without any gap. I already put new holes one inch away and mounted the curtains. I will fill the holes like your mentioned. Much appreciated.